# Merge multiple files into bigger files in Hadoop

Tags: hadoop

Is there a way I can merge a large number of files into a smaller set of files in Hadoop?

I have about 1000+ files that were created by a process.I would like to merge these files into 10 files on my local server.I have used getmerge but that merges that 1000+ files into 1 large file on my local server.I have used copyToLocal and that copies all the 1000+ files as it is.

Comment: [`cat`](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/FileSystemShell.html#cat)

Comment: Thanks,i've tried cat as well.cat merges the files in hdfs and not on the local machine.

Comment: I don't think there is a direct way.  You could create a simple map/reduce job using the Identity Mapper and Reducer and set the number of reducers to your desired number.